# Excel mode formula to exclude the returned value on a cell in the equation

Tags: excel

I have the following excel formula to return the most frequent text from a range and I would like to write another formula that returns the 2nd most frequent text and then the third and so on.

The original formula for the 1st most frequent text is entered in Cell B2:

```
=INDEX('Day 1 - 400'!I2:I1000,MODE(IF('Day 1 - 400'!I2:I1000<>"",MATCH('Day 1 - 400'!I2:I1000,'Day 1 - 400'!I2:I1000,0))))
```

I would like to add this function to cell B3 to return the 2nd most frequent text. Would an if function work?

Answer (score 1):

Build a Pivot Table with a count and sort by the count. That does not need any complicated formula at all.

Comment: I know but my boss wanted me to edit the original formula and I already told him we could use a pivot table. Boomers man.